# How to perform getitem or query to retrieve last updated record in DynamoDB without using primary key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I've recently started learning DynamoDB and created a table 'Communication' with the following attributes (along with the DynamoDB type):

Primary Key Communication ID (randomly generated seq # or UUID): String
Sort Key User ID: String
Attributes/Columns:
Communication_Mode: String
Communication_Channel: String
Communication_Preference: String (possible values Y/N)
DateTime: Number

Use case: User can choose not to be communicated (Communication_Preference: N) and after a month user may opt for it (Communication_Preference: Y); meaning for the same User ID there can be more than 1 record as PartitionKey is randomly generated number

If I have to query above table and retrieve last inserted record for a specific userid do I need to create Global Secondary Index on DateTime.

Can someone correct me if my understanding is wrong or propose me the best option to meet above requirement. Thanks!